# Merging elements in a list until certain text appears

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
list = ['BHX', 'AR', 'DEFab', 'ABR', 'DEFyr', 'HYt', 'wqw', 'DEF-a']
```

And i want to merge it to look like this:

```
merged_list = ['BHXAR DEFab', 'ABR DEFyr', 'HYtwqw DEF-a']
```

So basically i want to merge consecutive elements and when phrase 'DEF' is met it's the last element and and every next one creates another element, until again, DEF is met. It definitely looks like place for loop, i've been thinking about something with .append, maybe .next, probably itertools also may be used here, but i don't how to make it work properly.

Also, I'd want to merge elements with no space if none of them contains 'DEF', and with space when last element contains 'DEF'.

Comment: There is no research effort or attempted code

Comment: Try a simple loop, using `append` but without anything fancy like `next` or `itertools`. If you try that and are still stuck, show us your attempted code and tell us just where you are stuck. Hint: use the loop to build up the output string item, then when you reach an input string containing `'DEF'` finish the output string and append it to the output list.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Thanks for noting. I actually did try to write it by myself, and was trying to go with a for loop, but as my code wasn't making any sense i saw no point in posting it, but maybe i should just to see why it went wrong. And of course i've researched it earlier,but i didn't find any post with the same problem, and wasn't able to write solution myself basing on similiar problems.

@RoryDaulton Thanks for the advice. I went with wrong approach here, as I've tried to use something like `for a,b,c in list:` instead of just one variable (`'DE'F` would always be second or third).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic solution:

```
list = ['BHX', 'AR', 'DEFab', 'ABR', 'DEFyr', 'HYt', 'wqw', 'DEF-a']
merged_list = []
current = ''

for s in list:
    if s.startswith('DEF'):
        merged_list.append(current + ' ' + s)
        current = ''
    else:
        current += s
```

Comment: Thanks so much for help! 
It's simpler than I thought, and it looks that I had very wrong approach, because I actually tried to go with three different variables in a loop, with something like `for a,b,c in list:`
So it seems like I have to sit with the basics first :).

Answer (score 1):

another with a for loop

```
inlst = ['BHX', 'AR', 'DEFab', 'ABR', 'DEFyr', 'HYt', 'wqw', 'DEF-a']
tem=''
olt=[]

for i in inlst:
    if str(i).startswith('DEF'):
        tem  = tem + ' '+ str(i)
        olt.append(tem)
        tem=''
    else:
        tem  = tem + str(i)

print(olt)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for help. It's actually not adding space before "DEF", but it's fine too :).

Comment: added changes to include space also

Comment: Yes, it adds spaces now too. Thanks again for Your effort.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
mylist = ['BHX', 'AR', 'DEFab', 'ABR', 'DEFyr', 'HYt', 'wqw', 'DEF-a']
merged_list = ''.join([i.replace(i, i+'.') if 'DEF' in i else i for i in mylist]).split('.')

merged_list_final = [x.replace('DEF', ' DEF') for x in merged_list if x]

>>> merged_list_final
['BHXAR DEFab', 'ABR DEFyr', 'HYtwqw DEF-a']
```

What it does is first add an arbitrary character (`.`) to any item in your list that includes `DEF`, joins it all together into one long string, then splits it into smaller strings when that character is found. This results in:

```
>>> merged_list
['BHXARDEFab', 'ABRDEFyr', 'HYtwqwDEF-a', '']
```

Then, `merged_list_final` just replaces `DEF` with `DEF`, i.e. it adds a whitespace, *if* that strings is not empty (otherwise it skips over it).

Comment: Thanks so much for Your help. It's my fault that I used very simple example, because in my original file i have longer strings with both numbers, letters and punctuations marks, including (`.`), so if there's no (`.`) everything's fine, but if it appears then elements are divided. So i used other solution, but thanks for Your help once again!